# Does Chrome support GPU hardware acceleration for the 2D Canvas under Windows XP?

Tags: google-chrome, 2d, html5-canvas, gpu, hardware-acceleration

I keep reading conflicting answers to this question, and I can't find a definitive answer in an official Google document.

By suppressing the blacklist I can enable hardware acceleration for almost every rendering feature under chrome://gpu-internals/  but not the 2D Canvas.  My system is service pack 3, fully updated.  DirectX 9.  All drivers for the onboard video (Intel GMA3100) are completely up to date.  The chip is quite capable, and I even flashed my mobo BIOS to the latest version as a last ditch effort.  I'm thinking that Google just isn't supporting HW accel. for the 2D Canvas under Windows XP.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Chrome developers have disabled Canvas `HW Accel` for XP, it calls `Direct3DCreate9Ex` from `d3d9.dll` which is `DirectX 9L` available only on Vista+, but it is possible to wrap D3D9Ex on Windows XP via WineD3D Direct3D to OpenGL wrapper. (special thanks to WineHQ/Crossover)
Then we need to disable blacklist and disable sandbox in launch options. (Special thanks to BlackWingCat)

I have already managed to force HW accel for Chromium-based browsers for Windows XP/2003. And it works somehow.

**System requirements:**
CPU with SSE3 feature support, OpenGL 3.0 hardware/software support.
In fact I use video card from "green" company :)

**Installation:**
1. Copy and paste d3d9.dll, wined3d.dll, libwine.dll into chrome folder where you have chrome.exe, for example "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application"
2. Copy and replace d3dcompiler_47.dll and libwine.dll into your Chrome    folder where chrome.dll is, for example  C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\49.0.2623.112.
3. Add launch parameters "--ignore-gpu-blacklist --no-sandbox --disable-infobars" to your Chrome shortcut. (without quotes)
4. Run Chrome with your modified shortcut

If you experience issues with Chrome after this hack you can just remove launch options from Chrome shortcut it will disable this hack.

[image: Chrome 50 on Windows 2003 with HW accel enabled]

**Download:**
[ChromeHW_accel_XP.zip (tested with backported Chrome 50.0.2661.102 beta-m, Opera 37, Chrome 49)](http://mediafire.com/download/nt0n6sck5oajwc0/ChromeHW_accel_XP.zip)

**Known issues:**
1. Address bar flickers quickly when you type.
2. HTML5 video doesn't work correctly (you need to force to use Flash Player)

Actually, I can report that Opera 36/37 (chromium based) is a way more stable with this hw accel hack.

Comment: awesome. Tested with crome 27.0.1453.93. Without your patch 10 FPS, with your patch 46 FPS.
Using
https://developer.mozilla.org/media/uploads/demos/p/a/paulrouget/8bfba7f0b6c62d877a2b82dd5e10931e/hacksmozillaorg-achi_1334270447_demo_package/HWACCEL/

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

New Chromium builds use libGLESv2.dll version 1.2.0.2448.  I'm no expert in VB, but it seems as if the new version doesn't need the mod...

*HOWEVER -*

The new Chromium builds that use this new libGLESv2.dll always crash (And then restart automatically in safe mode) if you try to enable the overriding of GPU blacklist in flags.

If someone can check this out and report back it would be much appreciated (Could this have something to do possibly with the added support for DirectX 11?)

Answer (score 0):

Update patch is released, anyone interested can check